# Is it the correct place to store a header parameter in process.env for having different behaviour into my API application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is my context:

A NodeJs application deployed as lambda function offering an API.

I'd like to reuse the same application to offer different content depending on a request header.

So having this header "x-custom-header" sent through with the request I'd like to load a different configuration
and to provide a specific outcome payload.

When I get the request I'd like to store this header value into object

```
 process.env.mycustomHeader = requestHeader["x-custom-header"];
```

so I can possibly load on any file of the app the right configuration object like:

```
const config = getConfig(process.env.mycustomHeader);
```

Now : this is working fine on a single request test

But I'm worried and investigating about the behaviour of this process object in NodeJs w/ Lambda.

Can I be sure that this object life and scope is limited to a single request?
And there's no way that multiple different request might conflict accessing this process?
And lambda does not possible share reuse same NodeJs process, messing up with my idea/setup?

Any other better proposal to solve this use-case is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the object **inside** the lambda handler method, it will execute with each function call.

Comment: yes.  process.env.mycustomHeader = requestHeader["x-custom-header"];
Is execute on each the handler method.

Comment: You can be sure the life and scope of objects within the handler are per lambda invocation.